# Does Grunt review and give advice about CSS?

Tags: css, gruntjs

While running a standard Grunt task (Concat, minify and uglify) 1 issue was found twice:

```
autoprefixer: /The/path/to/my/output/file.css:4311:5: Replace fill-available to stretch, because spec had been changed
autoprefixer: /The/path/to/my/output/file.css:4413:5: Replace fill-available to stretch, because spec had been changed
```

Looking at my source .css file, I indeed found two instances of `-webkit-fill-available;`.

So, is grunt reviewing CSS code and giving advice about it?
Or is that a more serious issue..?

Comment: autoprefixer is reviewing your CSS code. It says so right there!

Comment: Sounds obvious now...
So Grunt isn't doing it, but autoprefixer is and it would prefer have me using stretch rather than fill-available, right?